# Bellman-Ford Algorithm- what value to use when there is no market?

Tags: algorithms

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/, section 4.4, Arbitrage Detection

If two currencies do not have a market, i.e. do not trade with each other, what value should be used for the currency trading matrix? zero/0?

Comment: See rates.txt table towards bottom of the page that lists exchange rates for various currencies. I think 0 should be used when there is no market but not sure.

Comment: You want it to be $0$ before taking the logarithms like they suggest. After taking the logarithm and negating, you should use $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dylan answered:

You want it to be 0 before taking the logarithms like they suggest. After taking the logarithm and negating, you should use ∞.